# Assigning characters in a substring to the original string for facet_grid labeller

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I apologise in advance for a lack of proper terminology here, most obvious in my title. I am self-taught, my rudimentry R skills stemming from a need to implement other people's code for biology research. Please correct where applicable.

So, to set up a working example use diamonds:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

diamonds <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
diamonds$cut <- factor(diamonds$cut,levels = c("Ideal", "Very Good", "Fair", "Good", "Premium"))

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, ..density..)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
p + facet_grid(. ~ cut)
```

Basically when i use my own data the names are too long for each of the facets of the grid, so I wanted to attribute shorter names without changing my data.

I found a post that said I can reassign names like this:

```
LAB_NAMES<-list('Ideal'="I", 'Very Good' = "V",
               'Fair'="F",'Good' = "G",
               'Premium'="P")
NEW_LABELLER<-function(variable,value){return(LAB_NAMES[value])}
```

Then adding the labeller to facet_grid

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, ..density..)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
p + facet_grid(. ~ cut,labeller=NEW_LABELLER)
```

This is fine for a once off, however I am generating a new list of names (e.g. "hsa-miR-4640-5p_hsa-mir-4640" "hsa-miR-548ap-5p_hsa-mir-548ap"...etc)
each time I look at a new condition in my experiment. You can see the names are quite long, but contain a common "_" in the middle. Thus, I can use sub to take the part of the name i want, for example, using diamonds we'll do something similar:

```
NAMES<-c("Ideal", "Very Good", "Fair", "Good", "Premium")
SHORT_NAMES<-substr(NAMES, 1, 1)
```

but *manually* putting these (relatively short) names back into the list for the labeller, is slow and tedious.

QUESTION: Is there an elegant way to assign the substring of short labels to the old string of long labels that recapitulates the way I have attributed them below, in one fell swoop?

```
LAB_NAMES<-list('Ideal'="I", 'Very Good' = "V",
               'Fair'="F",'Good' = "G",
               'Premium'="P")
```

Thank you all in advance. And thank you again to the regular and patient contributors to SO. I should acknowledge you if I ever finish this bloody PhD.

UPDATE - an example of the long names I generate in the object sig_miRs:

```
>sig_miRs()
[1] "hsa-miR-10b-5p_hsa-mir-10b", "hsa-miR-143-3p_hsa-mir-143",
                   "hsa-miR-146b-5p_hsa-mir-146b","hsa-miR-150-5p_hsa-mir-150",
                   "hsa-miR-196a-3p_hsa-mir-196a-2","hsa-miR-199a-3p_hsa-mir-199a-2",
                   "hsa-miR-199b-3p_hsa-mir-199b","hsa-miR-23c_hsa-mir-23c",
                   "hsa-miR-4326_hsa-mir-4326","hsa-miR-4485-3p_hsa-mir-4485",
                   "hsa-miR-668-3p_hsa-mir-668","hsa-miR-6840-5p_hsa-mir-6840"
```

The solution to my problem should take the list above and elegantly recapitulate this:

```
sig_miRs_short<-list('hsa-miR-10b-5p_hsa-mir-10b'="hsa-miR-10b-5p", 'hsa-miR-143-3p_hsa-mir-143' = "hsa-miR-143-3p",
                   'hsa-miR-146b-5p_hsa-mir-146b'="hsa-miR-146b-5p",'hsa-miR-150-5p_hsa-mir-150' = "hsa-miR-150-5p",
                   'hsa-miR-196a-3p_hsa-mir-196a-2'="hsa-miR-196a-3p",'hsa-miR-199a-3p_hsa-mir-199a-2'="hsa-miR-199a-3p",
                   'hsa-miR-199b-3p_hsa-mir-199b'="hsa-miR-199b-3p",'hsa-miR-23c_hsa-mir-23c'="hsa-miR-23c",
                   'hsa-miR-4326_hsa-mir-4326'="hsa-miR-4326",'hsa-miR-4485-3p_hsa-mir-4485'="hsa-miR-4485-3p",
                   'hsa-miR-668-3p_hsa-mir-668'="hsa-miR-668-3p",'hsa-miR-6840-5p_hsa-mir-6840'="hsa-miR-6840-5p")
    sig_miR_labeller<-function(variable,value){return(sig_miRs_short[value])}
```

Comment: Good work on this example. Looks like you're very much on the way, I think you might be in need of some regex here, but could you update your example with some of the original names and what your desired label based on those names would be?

Answer (score 2):

As you're only interested in the part before the underscore in your long name, there are various ways to acces it.

Option 1: using regular expressions. This labeller replaces every part of the string after the underscore (and the underscore) with an empty string.

```
sig_miR_labeller2 <- function(variable, value){
  return(gsub("_.+","",value))
}
```

Edit: here's how to use the labeller (and another option)

```
#making some testdata, sampling from the long names
set.seed(123)
nobs=500

sig_miRs_short<-list('hsa-miR-10b-5p_hsa-mir-10b'="hsa-miR-10b-5p", 'hsa-miR-143-3p_hsa-mir-143' = "hsa-miR-143-3p",
                     'hsa-miR-146b-5p_hsa-mir-146b'="hsa-miR-146b-5p",'hsa-miR-150-5p_hsa-mir-150' = "hsa-miR-150-5p",
                     'hsa-miR-196a-3p_hsa-mir-196a-2'="hsa-miR-196a-3p",'hsa-miR-199a-3p_hsa-mir-199a-2'="hsa-miR-199a-3p",
                     'hsa-miR-199b-3p_hsa-mir-199b'="hsa-miR-199b-3p",'hsa-miR-23c_hsa-mir-23c'="hsa-miR-23c",
                     'hsa-miR-4326_hsa-mir-4326'="hsa-miR-4326",'hsa-miR-4485-3p_hsa-mir-4485'="hsa-miR-4485-3p",
                     'hsa-miR-668-3p_hsa-mir-668'="hsa-miR-668-3p",'hsa-miR-6840-5p_hsa-mir-6840'="hsa-miR-6840-5p")

testnames <- names(sig_miRs_short)
testdata <- data.frame(x=runif(nobs),y=runif(nobs),miR=sample(testnames,nobs,T))
```

approach 1: using the labeller function. It takes in your long strings
and removes the underscore and everything after it.

```
sig_miR_labeller <- function(variable, value){
  return(gsub("_.+","",value))
}

p1 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~miR, labeller=sig_miR_labeller)
```

approach 2: don't use a labeller, but make a 'prettyvar' in your data and
use that for facetting (might be practical if you want to use facet_wrap instead,as that doesn't take a labeller argument)
    testdata$pretty_miR <- gsub("_.+","",testdata$miR)

```
p2 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(.~pretty_miR)
```

Both lead to:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, Heroka.

However, I fear I have misled you. The list of long names I generate does not contain the "=" symbol, nor the shortened form. I have edited the Q with a more accurate example. Furthermore, using diamonds example, the list would be equivalent to executing:  

> LAB_NAMES <- levels(diamonds$cut).

I apologise for my late response. Since my original post, I found other problems in my data that needed changing and took the opportunity to fix the names in the data, negating the problem. Nonetheless, I would still appreciate your insight, with this problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't understand the issue with '=' though, as I worked with the underscores.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand how to implement your solution. I generate the vector sig_miRs, which contains the list of long names, but sig_miRs doesn't appear in your code. How does then, or from what, does "return(gsub("_.+","",value)" extract the short names?

Comment: I found this answer helpful. When I implemented a similar recommendation, I got:   Warning messages:

2: The labeller API has been updated. Labellers taking `variable`and `value` arguments are now deprecated. See labellers documentation.